# Sample variance recursive relation. $n S_{n+1}^2 = (n-1)S_n^2 + \big( \frac{n}{n+1}\big) (X_n - \overline{X}_{n-1})^2$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, statistics

Let $\overline{X}_k$ and $S_k^2$ denote the sample mean and sample variance based on the first $k$ observations. Then establish the following 
$$n S_{n+1}^2 = (n-1)S_n^2 + \big( \frac{n}{n+1}\big) (X_{n+1} - \overline{X}_n)^2.$$

I am trying to use the relation 
$$\overline{X}_{n+1} = \frac{X_{n+1} + n\overline{X}_n}{n+1}.$$

I tried to decompose the sum into the first $n$ and the last $n+1$th term, however I get
$$n S_{n+1}^2 = \sum_{i=1}^{n+1} (X_i - \overline{X}_{n+1})^2 = \sum_{i=1}^n (X_i - \frac{X_{n+1} + n \overline{X}_n}{n+1})^2 + (\frac{n}{n+1} X_{n+1} - \overline{X}_n)^2,$$
which has the square of $\frac{n}{n+1}$. How can I get this relation? I would greatly appreciate some help.

Comment: I changed some things like $\overline{X_{n+1}}$ to things like $\overline{X}_{n+1}. \qquad$

Comment: @takecare: I don't have any helpful hints, but I've noticed a slight difference in the indices in the second term on the RHS of both of your equations.

Comment: Does this help: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/711135/derivation-of-runningonline-variances-formula/712036#712036

Comment: @takecare: Should the second term be $(X_n - \bar{X}_{n-1})^2$ or $(X_{n+1} - \bar{X}_{n})^2$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The key is to understand how to partition the sums of squares.  Consider a sequence of observations $\{x_i\}_{i \ge 1}$ and define from this sequence  $\{\bar x_n\}_{n \ge 1}$ where $\bar x_n = \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n x_i$.  Furthermore, define the function 
$$\begin{align*}
f_n(\delta) 
&= \sum_{i=1}^n (x_i - \delta)^2 \\
&= \sum_{i=1}^n (x_i - \delta' + \delta' - \delta)^2 \\
&= \sum_{i=1}^n (x_i - \delta')^2 + 2(x_i - \delta')(\delta' - \delta) + (\delta' - \delta)^2 \\
&= f_n(\delta') + 2(\delta' - \delta) \sum_{i=1}^n (x_i - \delta') + n(\delta' - \delta)^2 \\
& = f_n(\delta') + 2(\delta' - \delta) (n\bar x_n - n\delta') + n(\delta' - \delta)^2 \\
&= f_n(\delta') + n(\delta'-\delta)(2(\bar x_n - \delta') + (\delta' - \delta)) \\
&= f_n(\delta') + n(\delta'-\delta)(2\bar x_n - \delta' - \delta).
\end{align*}$$ 
So here we have a general relationship between the sum of squared deviations of $\{x_i\}_{i = 1}^n$ from some number $\delta$ and another number $\delta'$, and we are free to choose these values as we please.  So if we choose $\delta = \bar x_{n+1}$, and $\delta' = \bar x_n$, we obtain $$f_n(\bar x_{n+1}) = f_n(\bar x_n) + n(\bar x_n - \bar x_{n+1})(2\bar x_n - \bar x_n - \bar x_{n+1}) = f_n(\bar x_n) + n(\bar x_n - \bar x_{n+1})^2.$$  But $$(n-1)S_n^2 =  f_n(\bar x_n),$$ and $$f_n(\bar x_{n+1}) = f_{n+1}(\bar x_{n+1}) - (x_{n+1} - \bar x_{n+1})^2 = n S_{n+1}^2 - (x_{n+1} - \bar x_{n+1})^2,$$ so $$n S_{n+1}^2 = (n-1)S_n^2 + n(\bar x_n - \bar x_{n+1})^2 + (x_{n+1} - \bar x_{n+1})^2.$$  All that is left is to observe $$\bar x_{n+1} = \frac{n \bar x_n + x_{n+1}}{n+1}$$ and simplify.