# Express $x_{n+1}$ in terms of $n,\bar{x},s^2$.

Tags: probability, statistics, expected-value, descriptive-statistics

Consider a set of $n$ observations {$x_1,...x_n$}, with mean $\bar{x}$ and variance $s^2$.When a new observation $x_{n+1}$ is added to this set,the mean decreases,but the variance remains the same.Express $x_{n+1}$ in terms of $n,\bar{x},s^2$.

I can see that $x_{n+1}$ should lie below $\bar{x}$ but I cannot work with the equal variance criteria.

Comment: Did you try to express the new variance and make it equal to the previous expression of variance?

Comment: Refer to this question:  https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2837813/sample-variance-recursive-relation-n-s-n12-n-1s-n2-big-fracnn/2837838#2837838